# Making an array work in numerous methods?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm currently doing a project in school which involves reading integers from a .txt file and inputting them into an array. These integers will represent the amount of products that a team produces in a year. I then have to calculate the average productivity, highest etc...

Everything is going well so far and I know how to do this, the only thing I'm not sure of is how to make the array work in the other methods so that I can calculate the average. This is the code that I have so far. There are a few comments about menus that I haven't coded yet but hopefully you can see what I want to do, give the user an option if they want to see the average, highest or lowest productivity. The file which is being scanned is literally just a .txt file with a number on its own line (1 for each month).

```
/**
 * @author  Jack Orr
 * @version 1.0
 * @since   10-12-2014 
 */

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

// Begin by importing the utilities allowing for scanners and reading from files

public class Assignment {

    // main method which will call the other methods, employ a switch to choose
    // methods

    public static void main(String args[]) throws FileNotFoundException {

        readStats2012();
        readStats2013();
    }

    public static void readStats2012() throws FileNotFoundException {

        // This method reads the values from a keyboard scanner and assigns them to an array

        System.out.println("Productivity for 2012\n");
        ArrayList<Integer> teams = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int inTeam;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("in2012.txt"));
        while (in.hasNextInt()) {
            inTeam = in.nextInt();
            teams.add(inTeam);
        }

        in.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < teams.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Team " + (i + 1) + "\t" + teams.get(i));
        }
    }

    public static void readStats2013() throws FileNotFoundException {

        // This method reads the values from a keyboard scanner and assigns them to an array

        System.out.println("\nProductivity for 2013\n");
        ArrayList<Integer> teams = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        int inTeam;

        Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("in2013.txt"));
        while (in.hasNextInt()) {
            inTeam = in.nextInt();
            teams.add(inTeam);
        }

        in.close();

        for (int i = 0; i < teams.size(); i++) {
            System.out.println("Team " + (i + 1) + "\t" + teams.get(i));
        }   

    }
    static void calculateandDisplay(){

        // This will be a menu option to calculate the average, the highest and the lowest

        }

    public static double calculateAverage(){

        double average = 0;
        if(i = 0; i < teams.length; i++){

        }
        return average;

    }
}
```

Comment: Firstly, consider having a single method which takes the file name string as an argument instead of having identical code to read a particular year's data. What happens next year or the year after, or ten years from now; is it reasonable to have to write duplicated methods for each potential year?

Comment: That's a good point, your suggestion is much more practical!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you return the Lists and save these as local variable and pass these variables as arguments to the methods you want to call.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you refactor your two read methods to just one parametarised one:

```
public static void readStats(int year) throws FileNotFoundException {
    ...
    Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("in" + year + ".txt"));
    ...
}
```

Then use a static field of type List to hold all the data:

```
static List<List<Integer>> years = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
```

And at the bottom of your read method:

```
years.add(teams);
```